# Removing/Blocking access to my Twitter Profile from a 3rd Party

Tags: twitter

I am trying to clean my Google hits and I notice that a lot of them are Twitter services. Is there a way to block these services from making profiles for me on their site?

So far I am starting to revoke access to those [connections](https://twitter.com/settings/connections) I have authorized. But there are also other services that I have not given access.

- twitlist
- topsy
- favorious
- twistar
- twimages
- etc.

Would the only way be to set my profile to private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do anything about most of these third party services, because they only create a profile out of what you have publicly provided on the internet in most cases. You can try complaining at these sites and request for a removal, but then that might open you up to more spam, perhaps?
Revoking access would help only those legitimate app requests you have approved earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Some services can automatically grant access to themselves when you are specifying twitter username and password when you log in to this services. I can give a lot examples like Echofon, Tweetdeck, Twitpic... 
My advice - if you don't need this services anymore - revoke access to them, and if them will appear in your list later - change your password and complain to twitter administration.